# Using @Autowired of spring with scala

Tags: scala, spring-mvc, spring, autowired

i am using spring from scala and i am facing a problem when trying to inject a service with a trait/superclass.

This is my code:

```
trait MyServiceHolder{
  var myService:MyService = null

  @Autowired
  def setMyService(ms:MyService) = myService = ms
}

@RunWith(classOf[SpringJUnit4ClassRunner])
@ContextConfiguration(Array("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/application-context.xml"))
class MyConcreteClass extends MyServiceHolder{

  def hello() = myService.hello()  

}
```

This works:

```
@RunWith(classOf[SpringJUnit4ClassRunner])
@ContextConfiguration(Array("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/application-context.xml"))
class MyConcreteClass{

  var myService:MyService = null

  @Autowired
  def setMyService(ms:MyService) = myService = ms

  def hello() = myService.hello()  

}
```

The problem is that myService is null in my testcases. When looking at the bytecode level (class file) all annotations are present. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a form of the [Spring TestContext Framework](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/testing.html#testcontext-framework) to have your beans configured by Spring when running tests.